# can't pull from another remote after reverting merge from wrong branch

Tags: git, merge, pull, revert

I don't want to duplicate, but I don't see any questions/answers that exactly fit my situation.

So our team has to work with another team. I thought I was supposed to merge a feature branch of theirs into our release branch. Turns out it wasn't the right one.
I reverted the merge commit.
I found out that files added in the merge from their feature branch can't be added back when I tried to pull from their other branch they want me to use.
I reverted the revert.
I then manually "put back" all the changes that had happened in that first merge commit that I reverted and reverted again.
Now I still can't pull from the branch they want me to pull from.

**Which strategy would be the best to use at this point?**

Many branches, both sides, are being used by other team members, so my release branch being "broken" (the other team can't add their files back) is a big problem.

[image]

Comment: I think a little example with simple ascii branches would help us understand what is going on.

Comment: What do you mean by "files added in the merge can't be added back"?

Comment: Just in case: The correct branch that you had to merge includes revisions that were in the wrong branch that you merged/reverted before? If that is the case, git won't like it and getting around this might be a little troublesome. You might have to create separate clones of the branches so that git does not see that as revisions already merged in.... or you might have to rewrite your branch so that you get rid of the whole wrong merge altogether.

Comment: @eftshift0 like do a reset to the commit just before i did the merge of the wrong branch?

Comment: Yeah.... rewriting history is always a resource.... only a painful one if other people are already using the branch. But if you decided to to a `git reset --hard`, it is like it never happened in the first place. If it is a private branch (as in it hasn't been pushed, you are the only one who is using it locally, for example), do not think twice and reset it.

Comment: ... if it is a shared branch, the wrong merge is already up and everybody can see it, then you have to weight in to consider the best approach.

Comment: that's what i was thinking... @eftshift0
reset it to just before that merge commit, and manually add the changes that have occurred from our team to our release branch since i did that bad merge. other teams have pulled from it, but i think that will be ok.
i was just wondering/unsure... if i do the reset, it will actually be like the branch forgot about the resetting weirdness and will let me pull from their correct branch?

Comment: Ok.... if other people have already pulled from that, **do not rewrite**. It's still possible but it will be very painful.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yeah, it was files that were deleted when i reverted the merge that can't be added back again. it jus tsays "no changes" when i try to pull from the branch i want
same files in question in that new branch they want me to use. i cant pull, in this sense

Comment: @eftshift0 "do not rewrite"
so what do you suggest?

Comment: I am writing a possible answer.

Comment: Oh, my.... another person that shares my level of skills to do visuals :-D I guess we miss knowing where the right branch is in the visual aid.

Comment: By the way, i would like to know what the error is that git gives you when you try to merge _the correct branch_.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a dup or not because I'm not entirely clear what state you're in now. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67437113/184546) provides 3 options for proceeding after a reverting a merge commit that you later decide you needed. I suspect the last option of rebasing the branch you wish to re-merge in will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly from the question and follow-ups in the comments, you merged a branch, reverted it and now you want to merge a different branch that includes some revisions that were reverted as parts of the wrong branch, right?

Rewriting is not a viable path because other people are already using the wrong merge/reversion.

If that is the case, I think the next best-thing you can do to make git allow you to merge that branch is to rewrite history (privately) of the correct branch so that to git those are *really* new revisions. So, find the last common ancestor between your branch *before the bad merge* and the good branch you want to merge. That can be done with `git merge-base revision-before-bad-merge the-right-branch`. Let's call this revision `X`

```
git checkout X
git cherry-pick X..the-good-branch #I am assuming it's a straight line
```

Now, you have a private *clone* of the right branch that is made up of completely unmerged revisions to git. If you tried to merge this revision into the target branch, it should be fine:

```
git checkout target-branch
git merge HEAD@{1} -m "Merging a clone of branch whatever because I busted it merging the wrong branch before.... sorry"
```

Git should allow you to do that. As a warning: do that locally to see how it goes.

Comment: reading this over now, but i just added a visual, if it helps.

Comment: I have corrected the recipe. Make sure that my assumptions (first 2 paragraphs) are correct so that then the recipe is appropriate for your situation.