# git pr merge rolled back can't be done again properly

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I created a pr and merged it to `master`, but it had to be rolled back and the merged branch was recovered. Now I fixed the error and I want to make the merge again, but now `master` branch is overriding the changes in the merging branch, which means that all changes are lost with the merge. It seems git is taking master as ahead of the merging branch.

How can I instruct git to use changes in the merging branch as the ones to keep?

Comment: [Related.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67433104/184546) The answer there suggests reverting the revert like DavidDeutsch's answer below (which should work even if there are changes after the original revert). Also in that answer are 2 options. You can't do option 1, but option 2 shows you one way you can rewrite the commit IDs on your branch so that the PR will merge them in again.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the fixes were made to the same merging branch that was earlier merged into `master`. If that is the case, you must first revert the commit that rolled back that merge (i.e. revert the revert), then merge the merging branch back in. The first action undoes the rollback, whereas the second action merges in the fixes you made since that original merge.

Comment: I can't do that because other team members have merged changes to msater since the rollback

Comment: You can still revert the revert, despite later commits. Revert does not mean "erase commits". It means *add* a commit that *backs out* one *previous* commit.